# How to jump to a page without push current page into history?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a loading page, and a homepage (in webviews on mobile phones). The loading page will do some init things. And then jump to homepage. But if user click `back` it will back to the loading page. What I really want is that if user click `back` it will close the window if it is homepage at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to replace state, not push

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

```
history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 3", "bar2.html");
```

You can use it with all modern browsers and IE10+ 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Comment: And location.replace("url") on all browsers since the beginning of time

Comment: `location.replace("url")` might reload the page and for SPA apps it would be bad thing to do while it would reload all the app, not just change state of history

Comment: Sure - just added it for completeness sake.